# Check input for bad math expression

Tags: php, regex

Building a php calculator application and I'm a little confused on how I would do a specific case.

In general, I'm checking the input via a regular expression using `preg_match` but
what I'm confused about is how to cover the case of `09+0`, I want to make sure that no number has a zero and then a number to the right of it.

On the left, it can be anything other than `/` sign. Some more examples include the following : `01+100`, `33+011` etc (essentially, I want to let the user know this is bad input but having a difficult time figuring what the best way to check for it would be.

Edit 1 (Code so far) :

```
$input=$_GET["expr"]; 
$nospace_input=str_replace(' ', '', $input); 
$input = str_replace('--','+',$input);
$correct_format=preg_match("/^[-.,0-9][-+*.\/, 0-9]+$/",$input);


if ($correct_format==0 && $nospace_input=="") {
//do nothing
}

elseif ($divby_zero==1) {
  echo "Can't do div by zero!";
}

elseif($correct_format==1) {
  $result = eval('return ' .$input. ';');
  echo $input . " = " . $result;
}

else {
 echo "Not valid";
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have so far.

Comment: @RobLang Just updated

Comment: If you talk about users I think that you need to use a client programming languages like Javascript.
In your code you can delete the 0 from the left side, but is not necessary because if you return a int value, php delete the 0 automatically. now, for delete the 0 left side, you can use $number = ltrim($number, '0');. But I'm insist that if you want that the users know that put 0 in left side is incorrect, you need to use javascript.

Comment: http://lukaszwrobel.pl/blog/math-parser-part-1-introduction